# Is there a way to store fake attributes as an array instead of JSON?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-9

I am using Laravel Backpack's fake field attribute to store clicked checkboxes into the database. But I don't want it stored as JSON but as an array for example:

Not:

```
{ "key" : "value }
```

But as:

```
[ "value" ]
```

Here is more context:
https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields#optional-fake-field-attributes-stores-fake-attributes-as-json-in

Here is an example code snippet

```
protected function setupUpdateOperation()
{
    // The data for the checkboxes values
    $roles = Role::all();

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        CRUD::field('checkbox_' . $role->id)->type('checkbox')->label($role->description)->fake(true)->store_in('checkboxes_data');
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I just have to override the update method.

For example:

```
public function update($id)
{
    // Logic after update is done.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have collection you can simply iterate over it to extract values and store inside a separate array:

```
$roles = Role::all();
$role_values = [];

foreach($roles as $key => $value) {
    $role_values[] = $value;
}
```

The `$role_values` will now be a 1-D array containing:

```
['value 1','value 2', .... , 'value n']
```